# java string split based on new line

Tags: java

I have following string

```
String str="aaaaaaaaa\n\n\nbbbbbbbbbbb\n   \n";
```

I want to break it on `\n` so at the end i should two string `aaaaaaaa` and `bbbbbbbb`. I dont want last one as it only contain white space. so if i split it based on new line character using `str.split()` final array should have two entry only.

I tried below:

```
String str="aaaaaaaaa\n\n\nbbbbbbbbbbb\n   \n".replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
String[] split = str.split("\n+");
```

it ignore all `\n` and give single string `aaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbb`.

Comment: Because \s matches \n

Comment: Try `\\\n` to escape the `\`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the call to `replaceAll()`, which is removing the newlines too. Just this will do:

```
String[] split = str.split("\n\\s*");
```

This will not split on just spaces - the split must start at a newline (followed by optional further whitespace).

---

Here's some test code using your sample input with edge case enhancement:

```
String str = "aaaaaaaaa\nbbbbbb bbbbb\n   \n";
String[] split = str.split("\n\\s*");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

Output:

```
[aaaaaaaaa, bbbbbb bbbbb]
```

Comment: @wonce you're keeping me honest :) How about now?

Comment: Looks good, depending on what exactly was requested. It will now modify lines, removing leading (but bot trailing) whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
String str="aaaaaaaaa\n\n\nbbbbbbbbbbb\n   \n";
String[] lines = str.split("\\s*\n\\s*");
```

It will also remove all trailing and leading whitespace from all lines.

Answer (score 0):

The \ns are removed by your first statement: \s matches \n